# How to redraw View in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom view in which I play GIF which is actually a Loader. Whenever I do background work, I set GIF View visibility to ON and set its visibility to gone when work is done.  Following is my Custom GifLoader java code.

```
public class GifLoader extends View {

    private InputStream gifInputStream;
    private Movie gifMovie;
    private int movieWidth, movieHeight;
    private long movieDuration;
    private long mMovieStart;

    public GifLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public GifLoader(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public GifLoader(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                         int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context){
        setFocusable(true);
        gifInputStream = context.getResources()
                .openRawResource(R.drawable.loading);

        gifMovie = Movie.decodeStream(gifInputStream);
        movieWidth = gifMovie.width();
        movieHeight = gifMovie.height();
        movieDuration = gifMovie.duration();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec,
                             int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(movieWidth, movieHeight);
    }

    public int getMovieWidth(){
        return movieWidth;
    }

    public int getMovieHeight(){
        return movieHeight;
    }

    public long getMovieDuration(){
        return movieDuration;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        if (mMovieStart == 0) {   // first time
            mMovieStart = now;
        }

        if (gifMovie != null) {

            int dur = gifMovie.duration();
            if (dur == 0) {
                dur = 100;
            }

            int relTime = (int)((now - mMovieStart) % dur);

            gifMovie.setTime(relTime);

            gifMovie.draw(canvas, 0, 0);
            invalidate();

        }

    }

}
```

This is my XML code.

```
  <yas.life.utils.GifLoader
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/loading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Now the problem is, GIFview is running while its visibility is gone, whenever I set its visibility to visible the progress is already running, not from its initial state. What I want to do is the GIFloader should start from its initial state.
Is there anyway to restart this Custom GIFview whenever I set visibility to visible or any other way to achieve this.

Comment: Call init before set visible again.

Comment: Calling init is not working

Comment: try setEnabled(false);  when you hide it.

Answer (score 3):

Try to redraw your view calling `invalidate()`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()

Comment: Did you try to call init() and then invalidate() before show again GIF view?

Comment: No Just called invalidate

Answer (score 0):

I think [`Movie.setTime(0)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Movie.html#setTime(int)) may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the view visibility state in `onDraw()` and set gif time to 0 when view is gone